# dynamically changing the size of setDividerSize in JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to do what the title of question is. I have not figured out a way to do it. What is happening is the numeric value I put in is being changed to what is assigned to the int value of variable I have assigned. I am using a textField box to change the size of the setDividerSize property of JSplitPane. In other words,
    int newSize = 20 //default size of divider

```
jSplitPane.setDividerSize(newSize); //using the newSize variable

textField1.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int newSize1 = new Integer(textField1.getText());
                textField1.setText(new Integer(newSize).toString());
            }
        }); //method where I am trying to assign a new value to newSize to change
              the width of the divider
```

If I type in '5' I get '20' in the textField box.

I have tried this:

```
newSize.setText(new Integer(textField1).toString());
```

but I get an error of:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Integer(javax.swing.JTextField)
location: class java.lang.Integer
```

in netbeans.

Can someone please help me? I would appreciate it. If this is not enough code, please let me know and I will edit the original post to include it. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int newSize1 = new Integer(textField1.getText());
textField1.setText(new Integer(newSize).toString());
```

Note that in this code snippet you are reading the value from the textfield and replacing the text afterwards by another value (`newSize` vs `newSize1`). But you never set the value on the `JSplitPane`.

Looking at the rest of your posted code, I guess you try to update the value of the `newSize` variable and hope that that will update the `JSplitPane`. But changing the value of the `newSize` variable has no effect at all on the `JSplitPane`. You should call `jSplitPane.setDividerSize` with the value you read from the textfield

Comment: `jSplitPane.setDividerSize(newSize).setText(new Integer(newSize).toString());` Is this what you mean? If so, I am getting `void cannot be dereferenced` I do not believe I am calling it correctly. Would you mind if you can show me?

Comment: Ah got is, it's just `jSplitPane.setDividerSize(newSize1);` Thanks! You have been "checked".